# Deep linking with Query Parameter

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have this [link](http://example.com/?path_resolution=xyz&city=abc) which I want to link a specific activity on clicking this url.

I am able to link "http://example.com" to my application, but when I tried using this query parameter in the path prefix, it returned nothing.

I use this `intent-filter` to link my url :

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data
        android:host="example.com"
        android:scheme="http" 
        android:pathPrefix="/"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Here I don't know what is the path prefix for my Url.

Comment: How did you try to resolve this url in your application? Please provide some more input. Show your manifest declaration and the ADB command if you try it that way.

Comment: @ThomasR. - please check the edit. and i'm not trying by ADB command. I'm clicking this url from a mail.

Comment: because query string is not a path!

Comment: @Selvin - yeah i know that , that why i want to know how we link this type of urls to our applications

Comment: there is a many simlar questions even here on SO ... you can filter(actualy not filtering at all)  as you are doing now in some Activity without UI then check intent.getData() and start new Activity(and finish the UI-less one) based on query string ...

Answer (score 1):

It does not solve your problem, but to test your URL try this ADB command:

```
adb shell 'am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d "http://example.com?path_resolution=xyz&city=abc"'
```